ViewModelViewHost hosted in TabControl.ContentTemplate unexpectedly widens when its Height increases
I'm experiencing a problem with WPF layout that is really frustrating me.
The main app window is supposed to be divided into three principle panes. I've set up a 2x2 Grid. The rxui:ViewModelViewHost in Grid Column 0, Row 0 (R0C0) will display a bunch of content packaged into a ReactiveUserControl; I've replaced all that with a fixed-size placeholder for now, but the expectation is that the column should be sized to fit the necessary width of that ReactiveUserControl. I want the InstructionsTabControl in R1C0 to be stretched to match the width of the R0C0 contents, fill all available vertical height, and then lay out its internal content to whatever size it ends up getting.
The problem is that when I vertically resize the Window to any height greater than the window's initial Height, the rxui:ViewModelViewHost used in TabControl.ContentTemplate sprawls out wider than the content in R0C0, widening Column 0. I don't understand why this is. If I replace that ViewModelViewHost with the content of the View that it hosts, this widening behaviour stops. (Directly embedding content is not a practical solution, however, since the application relies on the ViewModelViewHost to choose different Views for different tab items.)

Here is the main window layout:
<rxui:ReactiveWindow 
        x:Class="DemonstrationTool.Demonstration"
        x:TypeArguments="local:DemonstrationViewModel"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemonstrationTool"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Width="800"
        Height="400"
        d:DesignHeight="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="400"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
        <rxui:ViewModelViewHost Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" 
                                x:Name="Controls"
                                ViewModel="{Binding Path=ControlsViewModel}" />
        
        <TabControl Name="InstructionsTabControl"
                    Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
                    TabStripPlacement="Bottom"
                    SelectedIndex="0">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StepViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="6" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StepViewModel}">
                     <!--If the VMVH is replaced with the contents of the resolved view (below), the layout problem stops--> 
                    <rxui:ViewModelViewHost ViewModel="{Binding}"
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                    <!--
                    This Border is the content of the resolved View.
                    Embedding it directly doesn't display the widening behavior.
                    --> 
                    <!--<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="BlueViolet" Background="DarkSalmon">
                        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            Placeholder for R1C0 content
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Border>-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>

        <!-- 
        Embedding the ViewModelViewHost directly as a Grid cell, rather than in the TabControl.ContentTemplate,
        doesn't demonstrate the widening behaviour either.
        -->
        <!--<rxui:ViewModelViewHost Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ViewModel="{Binding}"
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                                DataContext="{Binding Path=Steps[0]}"
                                Duration="0"/>-->

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightSkyBlue">
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Placeholder for C1 content</TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveWindow>

Here is the content of the view being rendered by the R1C0 TabControl's ContentTemplate's ViewModelViewHost, which is being unexpectedly widened:
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl 
    x:Class="DemonstrationTool.StepView"
    x:TypeArguments="local:StepViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemonstrationTool"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="BlueViolet" Background="DarkSalmon">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            Placeholder for R1C0 content
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>

And this is the (mock) view being rendered by the ViewModelViewHost in R0C0 of the main Window. The real view is auto-sized to fit its content (not an explicitly fixed size), but that content is pretty static, so in practice it turns out as a fixed width and height.
<rxui:ReactiveUserControl 
    x:Class="DemonstrationTool.ControlsView"
    x:TypeArguments="local:ControlsViewModel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:rxui="http://reactiveui.net"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DemonstrationTool"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=ViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Margin="4" Width="830" Height="250" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="Beige">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Placeholder for R0C0 content</TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</rxui:ReactiveUserControl>

Here is the ReactiveUI Splat configuration that rxui:ViewModelViewHost uses to resolve the View for the ViewModels:
        // Register views with Splat to support ReactiveUI View Location
        // https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/index.html
        Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new ControlsView(), typeof(IViewFor<ControlsViewModel>));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new StepView(), typeof(IViewFor<StepViewModel>));
        Locator.CurrentMutable.Register(() => new Demonstration(), typeof(IViewFor<DemonstrationViewModel>));

Can you tell me why the layout engine is behaving this way, and how I can fix it?

Replacing the rxui:ViewModelViewHost in the TabControl.ContentTemplate with <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/> (same layout configuration as the ViewModelViewHost) results in the layout behaving the way that I want. So it seems like the issue is that the rxui:ViewModelViewHost is interacting differently with the TabControl and layout engine than a Border with the same layout instructions would.

Replacing the contents of the TabControl's hosted view with <Border HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/> still shows the same layout issue, so it's definitely got something to do with how the ViewModelViewHost handles sizing.

If I delete the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" configuration from the R1C0 TabControl ViewModelViewHost, then start the app in debug mode, then add those layout attributes (with VS applying the XAML change to the running app "live"), the layout behaves the way that I want. If I then restart the application with those attributes in place, the ViewModelViewHost layout starts misbehaving again. I have no idea why that would be the case.

Just remove the DockPanel's size bindings. This is what's actually forcing the content to resize. If a parent resizes all it's children will calculate their layout again and resize themselves based on the available space. Or flip the columns and give the first a width * and the second Auto (and probably then column content a fixed width) . Or give the document a fixed width.

The DockPanel will stretch to fill all available space automatically (in your example the DockPanel is even redundant). That's why the binding doesn't make sense. It only introduces issues for example because ActualWidth of the parent doesn't respect Padding. Or it disables/breaks proper resizing behavior where the parent can't properly resize to accommodate its child (your case, because UserControl is a ContentControl that by default resizes to allow its child to fit).

If you want the document to be resized and take up the available space then flip the columns as mentioned before (in terms of width constraints). If you want the right column to resize (to take up the available space) then leave it as it is (without the binding).

@BionicCode thanks for your suggestions. The DockPanel was a leftover from the simplification-for-SO process (it was not redundant in original code) but I've completely removed it now, along with the Width/Height bindings you mentioned. The problem still exists. I've updated the code in the question with a simpler version which still demonstrates the ViewModelViewHost widening behavior which I'm concerned about.

I'm currently working around the problem by ensuring that the UserControl hosted in R0C0 can adapt to varying container widths, and then applying a fixed width for Column 0 in the main window layout (rather than using Auto). However this workaround won't be robust if control sizes change due to localisation (different UI text elements) so I'm still interested in addressing the true root cause.
